# what is the recommended smallest value of AIC or BIC?

Tags: categorical-data, dataset

to now how small it is! in addition what value of AIC and BIC are the minimum value it get manly for categorical data analysis

Answer (score 0):

The Information criteria become smaller the better a model fits but they penalize large numbers of predictors that may lead to overfitting. The absolute values of AIC or BIC are not of interest. Instead, relative values of different models fit to the same data are or interest.
Given a set of candidate models for the data, the preferred model is the one with the minimum AIC/BIC. This is relative between the different candidate models.

Comment: tank you respect

Comment: Please read "What should I do if someone answers ?" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers